# php selenium test find value of third td from table

Tags: php, selenium

Hello Friends i am try to use selenium in YII which is PHP framework. i am trying to do selenium testing on my dynamic data but when i am trying to access specific TD data then i am not able to do that can i use like this

```
"//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2][.='value2']
```

for my selenium test as i need to find value from like

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr class=odd>
   <td> value1 </td>
   <td> value2 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

i am using this code

```
$this->assertElementPresent("xpath=//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2][text() = 'value2']");
```

and this is result i am getting.

```
PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed command: assertElementPresent('xpath=//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2][text() = '0']')
```

Failed asserting that false is true.

now in this i need to find value2 with php selenium test.

Comment: i have tried many things like 
$this->assertElementPresent('//table/tr/td[contains(text()="ÆRØ ENERGI- OG MILJØKONTOR")]'); but not able to work

Comment: Does it throw an error? Is there a specific reason that you aren't showing actual formatted HTML code?

Comment: this is the error : PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed command: assertElementPresent('xpath=//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2][text() = '0']')
Failed asserting that false is true.

Comment: no their is no specific reason for html format just casually so that we can understand quickly..

Comment: Please add all clarifications to you question by editing your question. The default HTML format would be preferred.

Comment: in simple word i just to confirm that my 2nd td value is  = "value2" with selenium test. as when i am trying to assess the value i am not able to access it.